# Is this ethical? Copying unvoted answer into upvoted deleted answer after question merge

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, deleted-answers, ethics

Earlier today, I wrote a quick answer on a question, and received an upvote. I then saw a comment on the question identifying it as an exact duplicate (the asker had asked the same question twice within minutes). I then deleted my answer, and voted to close the duplicate question, before writing a new, longer answer on the original question. This new answer received no upvotes.

I later noticed that the duplicate question hadn't been closed (lack of 3k+ attention, I suppose) and had received a bit of action in the interim. Because of this, I flagged the question for moderator review, and recommended merging the questions.

This left me with two answers on the same question - one with a detailed answer with no upvotes, and another shorter, deleted answer with one upvote.

What I did next might constitute reputation whoring. I copied the text from the unvoted answer into the upvoted answer, then deleted the unvoted answer and undeleted the upvoted answer.

I think this is OK because the longer answer was a superset of the shorter one, so the upvote was still valid. I'd just like the community to weigh in on whether or not what I did was ok.

Is this sort of behaviour allowed, and do you consider it ethical?

Comment: in the end, he still has a better answer then if you had not bothered. i believe both where your answers and thus up to you how you wanted to deliver the answer in the best way for both of you. So i think its perfectly fine. However, i think this question might be very subjective from person to person.

Comment: @Andy: I think I'm ok with it mainly because had I not known it was a dupe, I would have edited the upvoted answer into the longer answer anyway, so I'm just "setting history right."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds fine to me.  Someone found your original answer helpful and upvoted it.  Your new answer now contains that same information (and more), so I don't see any harm in keeping the vote.

Comment: That was my rationale. It's nice to have a mod back it up though.